# Blender animation file turn into "Textedit" file and never came out as a video

Tags: export, video-sequence-editor, osx

I'm new in blender (I started in January 2018), this is the first time I try to get an animation and it still doesn't work "as expected".
I used JPEGs as frames when I rendered first into animation, after I created a new file in which I added them in the video editing mode.There is (only) 100 frames and the preview looks good. When I render the animation in the video editing mode, I finally get a file that is neither a .MP4, or a .avi, or .mov BUT a sort of "Textedit document".

To fix it I already try to change the output, the codec, the quality & rapidity for the render. (even switched from blender render to cycles render too, to see if something different could happen)

[image: the kind of stuffs that came out every time I try what I'm telling here]

Comment: Did you try renaming the file to have a .mp4 extension?

Comment: do you mean before saving the file or after the export ?

Comment: I also had this problem and the File Extensions check box was unchecked under Render: Output tab. Checking the box fixed it. I also was able to manually add the correct extensions, which did work but was very labour intensive. Maybe easier to just rerender with the extension box checked.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem myself. You need to have *File Extensions* checked under *Render: Output* tab and then it will be saved in the correct file format - PNG in my case.